# How can I contribute to Monero as a software developer

Tags: programming-languages

I work as a software developer for my day job. I recently gained a lot of interest in the Monero project and I'd like to contribute. How can I start?

Answer (score 6):

The primary ways to start are to become familiar with the [codebase](https://github.com/monero-project/monero), the [cryptonote standards](https://cryptonote.org/standards/), and to engage with other developers. All of the developers communicate via IRC on #monero-dev or #monero on [freenode's IRC servers](https://freenode.net/).

Documentation is severely lacking so the most efficient way to obtain any information that you can't find is to ask on #monero or #monero-dev. Please stick around, your question will eventually be answered.